# file.exe has trigger a breakpoint in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, oop, visual-c++

Sorry, this must be a very basic error, but i searched it everywhere and it seems can't fix my problem, i'm simply just doing some "input and output array" for my OOP class, i use dynamic allowcation for my array, here's my code, and i know it's only the delete error, others (create, insert,... work fine), big thanks to all :

i tried `delete [] a;` `delete a` also, but it didn't work, i tried putting `system("pause")` right after it (i googled this), but also no :((

```
void shift_left_array(int *a,int k , int &n, int step = 1) {
    // k : begin position
    // n : end position
    for (int i = k; i < n; i++) {
        *(a + i - 1) = *(a + i); // Shift right array
    }
}

void delete_from_array(int *a, int &n) {
    int k; // delete position
    // shift left, then resize array
    cout << "Which position do you want to delete ? (Type from 0 to " << n - 1 << ") : " << endl;
    cin >> k;

    shift_left_array(a, k + 1, n);
    n--; // resize array

    delete (a + n); // Trigger break point error here
}

int main() {

    int n = 0;
    int *a = new int[n];

    cout << "Insert array size : " << endl;
    cin >> n;

    // Create new array
    create_array(a,n);
    display_array(a,n);
    // Add more value to array (increase array size)
    insert_to_array(a, n);
    display_array(a, n);

    // Delete value from array
    delete_from_array(a,n);
    display_array(a, n);

    // Sort
    bubble_sort(a,n);
    display_array(a, n);
    // Search
    linear_search_array(a, n);
    // Update
    update_array_value(a, n);
    display_array(a, n);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can `delete` only what was returned by `new`. `(a+n)` is not that. It's C++. Use std::vector. Or switch to C.

Comment: `int *a = new int[n];` what value of `n` is in this line?

Comment: You are creating an array with size 0. What happens with this array in `create_array`

Comment: Raw pointers and naked new / delete are complex and can usually be avoided. In this case you can avoid them. Save your time and avoid them.